# Tomar caracteres antes del simbolo "-"

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista de carpetas para leer su contenido, solamente lo que necesito es saber como tomar el nombre que esta exactamente antes de este caracter " - "

Asi es como se miran los nombres de las carpetas:

```
abcdegf#2-f7
hijklmnñodcdcd#3-b9
```

Como se puede ver algunas tienen mas caracteres antes de tal caracter.

Y ademas como puedo tambien eliminar el # es decir que quede solamente asi "abcdef 3"

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? De ser ese el caso, agrega el código por favor. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En c# seria así:

```
string frase = "abcdegf#2-f7";
string primera_palabra = frase.split('-')[0];
Console.WriteLine(primera_palabra);
```

Con split es facil aqui mas documentacion [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Queda de esta manera hijklmnñodcdcd#3, como puedo quitar el # y que quede con espacio, asi : hijklmnñodcdcd 3

Comment: @cosito Enves de hacer split por el '-' hazlo por el '#'